# Unexpected character: '?' @ line 1, column 1. ?pluginManagement {

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

After flutter I'm facing this issues how I can resolve this issues.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  settings file 'E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle': 1: Unexpected character: '?' @ line 1, column 1.
     ?pluginManagement {
     ^

  1 error


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

---

```
**Okay, When i update flutter in latest version 3.19+, it something print on console look likes your previous gradle... deprecated. after that when i update my gradle 8.5 that time this message shows**


**Console Error**
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Could not compile settings file 'E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  settings file 'E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle': 1: Unexpected character: '?' @ line 1, column 1.
     ?pluginManagement {
     ^

  1 error


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**-----------------------------------------------------------**
**See why it says settings.gradle in which view code (console error indicated ? in setting.gradle)**

    pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"

**android/build.gradle codes**

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

**app/build.gradle codes**

    plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}


def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}



def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    namespace "com.jobkar.hiredge"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jobkar.hiredge"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}


**gradle.wrapper.properties codes list**

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip
```

Comment: I think we would need to see the contents of the `E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle` file to see what it was doing. The error seems to suggest that it's an unexpected character in the file. It could be that you just need to tweak it.

Comment: i have added codes here please see

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that You accidentally placed a question mark **?** in the first line of the `settings.gradle` file.

Go to `E:\Completed\Hiredge\jobkar_pro\android\settings.gradle` and delete from the first line this -> **?**

Comment: i have added codes please see

Comment: i have not added or placed any ? mark inside this page settings.gradle , if i remove all codes from this page after that this issues shows when run app, you can upside all codes